# Dynamically how to get lat and lang of particular searched area

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, api

I am trying to get the lat and lang of the location. So, let me explain the concept that i need to do.

There will be a search box in the front end UI. Currently in my python code i am passing search area,lat and lang statically. Now the thing is that, in the front end UI i will be typing the search area in the text box and i will click on search. So, the search term should pass to the back-end api and it need to get the lat and lang of that particular area.

Is there any Google API to pass the search area and get the lat and lang dynamically?

Below is my python code. Note, this is not the full code. This is the code lines i am concentrating on.

```
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    lat_lng={'lat': 12.9250, 'lng': 77.5938}, 
    location='jayanagar', 
    keyword='bakery',
    radius=1000, 
    types=['types.TYPE_BAKERY'])
```

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you use **geopy** https://pypi.org/project/geopy/

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="your_app_name")

>>> location = geolocator.geocode("jayanagar bangalore")
>>> print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(12.9292731, 77.5824229)
>>>
```

Comment: Thank u so much. Let me try this

Comment: Error in print command. I am not able to print lat and long, Below is the code.
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    location = geolocator.geocode("jayanagar bangalore"),
    #lat_lng={'lat': 12.9250, 'lng': 77.5938}, 
    #location='jayanagar', 
    keyword='bakery',
    radius=1000, 
    types=['types.TYPE_BAKERY'])
    print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
Error:
  File "map.py", line 22
    print((location.latitude, location.longitude)))
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: @shivalal you removed print line ? which was causing the error because I can't find that in code

Comment: I updated the code and shared you the new link. Please check

Comment: can you uncomment line 10,11,12 and see if thats working

Comment: IF we uncomment those three lines means it is working fine. But the print command is not working inside query_result.. I dont know why...

Comment: As you told, i have passed arguments in order. But according to your solution, i need to pass location 2 times. Then it will come. please check the below link: https://pastebin.com/w63GDHjV

Comment: @shivalal are you using https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places

Comment: Yes I have used the same code. If you observe that github code, they also passed lat and lang statically.

Comment: let's discuss here http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit&togetherjs=x6DatxtRDc